# C - read stdin until ctrl+d not working

Tags: c, crash, line, fgets

I read somewhere that `while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin) != NULL)` should read from standard input until you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> which represents `EOF` and generates NULL, but my program keeps going even though I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, anyone have any ideas? everything is appreciated.

Comment: windows? use CTRL+Z then.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> is **not** defined as EOF in the C language specification. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> is defined **at the operating system level**. Therefore, you must be on a system on which <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> has not the behaviour you expect.

Comment: thanks! I tried on Linux instead of Windows and now it works as it should! IT was meant to work in Linux so that's what matters anyways!